# Why High Volume Customer Portal license is duplicated on PDE?

Tags: licenses, userlicense, duplicate-management

I am trying to implement a custom free package to screen scrape Salesforce Company Profile page and extract Users Licenses Total, Used and Remaining numbers.
I was inspired [by this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dqh3AAC) and I believe I can do it faster than Salesforce releases such functionality.

During screen scrape, I try to match the license by its name, assuming it is unique. It was working fine on Developer Edition, but when I migrated this app to Partner Developer Edition, I have encountered that one license is duplicated and this causes my application to fail
[image: High Volume Customer Portal license comes twice, once with 20 Total Licenses and second time with 10 Total Licenses]

High Volume Customer Portal license comes twice, once with 20 Total Licenses and second time with 10 Total Licenses.

Does anyone knows why High Volume Customer Portal license is duplicated on PDE?
Is it duplicated on any other orgs?

I see these tow 'tr' rows are completely identical except number or Total\Remaining licenses, is there any way to distinguish them?

Does anyone has any suggestions how this issue can be overcome?

================================================================================

Update: also I have noticed this applies only for the new created organization from trial hub, and this doesn't apply to another PDE organization, which was created two years ago at 23/01/2014.